# Java - Json string to objects using Gso

Tags: java, json, gson

Struggling here to convert a JSON string containing objects
to objects using GSON.

**The JSON array**

```
[
 {"_id":"11111",
  "_owner":"2222",
  "name":"S32B - TankFever",
  "__v":0,
  "slots":[],
  "members": 
  [
    {"_email":"mail@gmail.com",
     "key":"XXX",
     "_id":"33333",
     "accepted":false
    },
    {"_email":"mail@hotmail.nl",
     "key":"XXX",
     "_id":"44444",
     "accepted":false}
  ]
 }, and some more.
]
```

The array contains objects I called 'TimeSheet'. And each timesheet contains an array of objects called: 'Slot' and 'Member'.

**The classes**

Timesheet

```
private String _owner;
private String name;
private Slot[] slots;
private Member[] members;
```

Member

```
private String _email;
private String key;
private boolean accepted;
```

Slot (is still empty)

Code I thought which should work:

```
String jsonString = response.body().string();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Timesheet>>(){}.getType();
List<Timesheet> inpList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);

for (int i=0;i<inpList.size();i++) {
     Timesheet x = inpList.get(i);
     System.out.println(x);
}
```

The error I'll get (It doesn't say anything about Gson but it does throws an exception here with debugging)

```
04-09 23:13:17.242 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
04-09 23:13:17.242 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:378)
04-09 23:13:17.242 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:956)
04-09 23:13:17.243 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:92)
04-09 23:13:17.243 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:83)
04-09 23:13:17.243 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:109)
04-09 23:13:17.243 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at com.example.jim.app.model.User.getOwnedTimesheets(User.java:169)
04-09 23:13:17.243 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at com.example.jim.app.fragment.TimesheetsFragment.initializeTimesheetsListView(TimesheetsFragment.java:91)
04-09 23:13:17.243 1594-1594/com.example.jim.app I/System.out:     at com.example.jim.app.fragment.TimesheetsFragment.onCreateView(TimesheetsFragment.java:73)
```

If some additional information is needed, I will update this question asap!

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @Pillar sorry, I totally forgot the error message I'll get!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the JSON or Gson. Your response stream is closed.

Comment: @Pillar thanks for thinking here with me, not sure why but the response whas indeed close on which I was confused while debuggen, because other code where I was using this one the exact same way worked just fine..

Comment: @JimVercoelen Are you reading the response body 2x? You can only call string() once.

Comment: Ah that should be the problem here! Already fixed it but didn't know the issue was, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Since the object `Type type` refers to `Timesheet`
 then this statement will generate the exception

```
List<Timesheet2> inpList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

instead you should use the same class as the `type`  i.e

```
List<Timesheet> inpList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Comment: Thanks for watching here with me. I did use the correct class but posted the wrong code.. I changed my post.

Comment: It will generate the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed` ?